# how to create ticket using vtiger CRM web service

Tags: vtiger

I am trying to use doCreate method in vTiger CRM web services using java WS client.

when i have tried to create FAQ

```
Map valueMap = new HashMap();
    valueMap.put("faqstatus", "Draft");
    valueMap.put("question", "This is WS client question");
    valueMap.put("faq_answer", "This is WS client answer");

    JSONObject result = client.doCreate("Faq", valueMap);
```

No error is return in the console but the result is null..

what may be the issue. how to resolve this null.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the element `faqcategories` to your HashMap.
This is a JSON representation that works for me:

> {      "faqcategories" : "General",    "faqstatus" : "Draft",      "question" : "How to do that?", "faq_answer" : "this is how you do that"  }

Without adding `faqcategories`, [Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en) result from the creation request of the new entity is "MALFORMED JSON"